# Volume control applet doesn't work, but alsamixer does!

Tags: sound, volume-control

My volume control applet and the "Sound Preferences" / "Output Volume" doesn't work (it doesn't affect the volume).

`alsamixer` on the other hand works.

Any ideas of what could cause this? (Running natty with Gnome 2.32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this type of behaviour when you aren't adjusting the output volume on the active audio output device. In my case when I connected a USB audio device audio output would switch to it, however the volume control would control the unused onboard audio.

If you open the sound settings window do you see more than one output device? Does the volume control on one of the output devices work correctly?

Here's some (solutionless) discussion of the same issue: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-media/+question/5735

Comment: Problem fixed by disabling the sound device I wasn't using. Thanks.

Comment: That works great, when it's an option. I'd love it if someone could improve this answer with a solution that works when you can't disable the device. I understood that the cause was a bug that was going to be addressed.