# Ubuntu 18.04 : Volume control on system doesn't change volume but volume control on video players does

Tags: 18.04, sound, volume-control

So my title describes the problem pretty much entirely. I can't get the volume to change using the system volume control via my keyboard or through the volume drag bar accessed through the "Activities" bar on the top of the screen.

But I can get it to mute both of those ways. Additionally I've been able to control volume through the video player volume controls (youtube/netflix etc) that are available to me while watching videos.

How do I get the system volume control working again?

Comment: This sounds like it's most likely a dupe of [volume control applet doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115069/volume-control-applet-doesnt-work-but-alsamixer-does?rq=1). Does alsamixer (on the command line, eg via Gnome Terminal, Ctrl+Alt+T) work?